# Java stream map and collect - order of resulting container

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

```
List<MyObject> myList = new ArrayList<>(); 
//populate myList here

List<String> nameList = myList.stream()
        .map(MyObject::getName)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In above code, can I expect that order of `MyObject` names in `nameList` is always the same as the order of `myList`?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Yes, you can expect this even if you are using parallel stream as long as you did not explicitly convert it into [`unordered()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#unordered--) mode.

The ordering never changes in sequential mode, but may change in parallel mode. The stream becomes unordered either:

- If you explicitly turn it into unordered mode via `unordered()` call
- If the stream source reports that it's unordered (for example, `HashSet` stream is unordered as order is implementation dependent and you cannot rely on it)
- If you are using unordered terminal operation (for example, `forEach()` operation or collecting to unordered collector like `toSet()`)

In your case none of these conditions met, thus your stream is ordered.

Comment: That is not true. A parallel stream is performed one or more elements at a time. Thus the map() would preserve the encounter of the stream order but not the original List's order. 
p.s if you are use `list.stream().parallel().map(i)...` that would preserve the stream order.